# webpack-dev-server opens localhost:8080/undefined

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I run `$ npm run dev` (`"dev": "webpack-dev-server"`) it opens localhost:8080/undefined instead of localhost:8080 or at least localhost:8080/index.html

webpack-config.js devServer part:

devServer: {

```
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),

    compress: true,

    stats: "errors-only",

    hot: true,

    open: true
```

If I delete the /undefined part of the URL it works properly even the hot module replacement so it's not a big problem; just want to know why is that happening.

Edit: Im on MacOS

Edit2: Console info when `npm run dev`:

`Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from /Users/cozarkd/folders/dist
webpack: wait until bundle finished: /undefined
webpack: Compiled successfully.`

Ty

Comment: What is `output.publicPath`?

Comment: Im not sure what do you need but maybe this helps:
(edited the main post because don't know how to write on comment properly)

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Webpack v3 (for me, the server opens `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/`). Which version of Webpack are you using?

Comment: Webpack 2.5.1
webpack-dev-server 2.4.5
Should I try to update?
I remember that this same project worked fine on my last computer (still does, just the undefined thing)
When I ran npm run dev I got localhost:8080 and index.html opened.
I still can do that but only manually deleting /undefined from the url

Comment: Ouch sorry, never mind, I was using an old version of `webpack-dev-server` :-( I just updated to 2.5.0 and it's showing the same error. Looks to be a bug: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/960

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a bug: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/960

A quick workaround is offered ([here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/960#issuecomment-311477326)):

```
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  compress: true,
  stats: "errors-only",
  hot: true,
  open: true,
  openPage: '' // <-- this
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems that u got better searching skills than me :P